# How do I use Git when using Composer?

Tags: version-control, composer

I am working on an OpenSocial project and its installed via composer. I am having a folder structure as below:

- composer.json
- composer.lock
- html
  (Drupal Installation.)
- vendor
  (Dependencies)

When creating, should I add the all files including composer.json and vendor to the Git repository, or just the *html* directory?

In some cases, for example in a normal Drupal 8 installation the Composer files and the *vendor* directory are in the same directory as the Drupal files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no, you do not need to commit the vendor folder, because the contents are built using composer.lock and composer.json (both should be committed) when running `composer install`. *Some* people have to commit vendor due to their hosting constraints and/or having no build process (where the application is built for deployment).

IMO management via Composer with vanilla D8 tarball is very difficult as it lacks the structure to facilitate solid version control, project management and patching workflow that others like [Drupal Project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) or [Acquia BLT](https://github.com/acquia/blt) offer.